# Line containing the Random Vector $(X - Y, 2X - 2Y + 2)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d random variables with distribution N$(0, 1)$.

$a)$ Prove that $\vec{W} = (X - Y, 2X - 2Y + 2)$ has degenerate normal bivariate distribution.

$b)$ What is the line containing the values of the vector $\vec{W}$?

I have already proved that $\vec{W}$ has degenerate normal bivariate distribution, but I'm clueless about obtaining the line of the random vector.

**Answer:** $y = 2x + 2$.

**Edit:** I noticed that if you weirdly treat the random vector as an ordered pair, it becomes $(x, 2x +2)$, so $y = 2x + 2$, but I imagine a proper solution is not that trivial.

Comment: The "proper solution" to part (b) is as trivial as that. Part (a) is a bit more involved.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I can’t remember the last time a probability problem was that easy :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line is simply $$(X-Y,2(X-Y)+2),$$ i.e., the $y$-coordinate is $2x+2$ where $x=X-Y$.